# adding RTF-tagged text to flowdocment in codebehind

Tags: wpf, flowdocument, richtext

I have rich text stored in a database with full RTF tagging, like so:

```
{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\cf1\f0\fs17 Email sent on 10/1...
```

I want to make this text the source for a WPF FlowDocument.  When I add this text to a paragraph directly, I see all of the tagging in the document.

```
   fd = New FlowDocument

   p = New Paragraph()
   p.FontSize = 12
   p.Foreground = Brushes.Black
   p.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal
   p.Inlines.Add(New Run(vVariableWithRTFTagsInIt))
   fd.Blocks.Add(p)
```

How do I tell the FlowDocument that I'm adding tagged RTF?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, lots of FlowDocument operations are done using TextRange class.
Check out [TextRange.Load Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.load.aspx):

```
TextRange range = new TextRange(fd.ContentStart, fd.ContentEnd);
range.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
```